# When are funds available for a withdraw or to trade after a Futures /ES Emini contract? T+3 settlement

Tags: stock-exchanges, stock-markets, futures

Stocks seem to have a 3 day wait (trade plus 3) T+3 for funds to be available to place another trade or withdraw cash without getting a "FED CALL".  Options seem to have a 1 day wait.
When are funds available for a withdraw or to use to trade after a Futures /ES Emini contract?  Is it the same time for /CL and /NQ?
When are the funds settled and available for withdraw OR available to use in another trade?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't sell options if you don't have margin account (except covered call).
2. You can't trade futures if you don't have margin account.
3. Everything is **immediate** when you have margin account. (Including stocks)
4. Margin account is not subject to freeriding rules, but is subject to Pattern Day Trader rules.

Answer (score 1):

Futures are immediate settlement, and your money is available as soon as you close out your position.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean I can trades the same funds multiple times each day?    If I put $25,000 into a margin account and trade $25K in the morning, I can trade the other $25K in the afternoon using margin.  But then I would be done until it settles T+3.  My max trading in one day would be $50K.    CAN I USE funds multiple times for futures trading each day?  With a $25K deposit can I place round trip trades 4 times and buy & sell the same funds all day?  Would the maximum amount of trading funds be unlimited?

Comment: Would the maximum amount of trading funds be unlimited?

Comment: @fred Again, it is immediate, not T+Something. With $25,000, you can buy at 9:30:00, sell all after 1 second, buy again, and sell after another second, repeat thousands of times.